# restart timer in java

Tags: java

I would like to do a timer, it will be restarted when  something happens:

```
public static Timer timer;

public myTimer(long MAC, String ipAddress){
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 120000); 
}

public void update(){
    timer.cancel();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 120000); 
}
```

I have a problem when I create the new schedule, I have this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:358)
    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:170)
    at spb.keepAliveTimer.update(keepAliveTimer.java:37)
    at spb.keepAlive.update(keepAlive.java:58)
    at spb.receptor.keepAlive(receptor.java:475)
    at spb.receptor.run(receptor.java:118)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I don't know how can I do it! Thanks!

Comment: and remove timer = new Timer(); that shouldn't be necessary

Comment: Please also include timerTask (and what is the long MAC param for? don't see it being used)

Comment: new Timer() is necessary because else there will be no thread.

Comment: Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75033062/5645656).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works fine for me... can you paste the full code and error?

```
package snippet;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {
    public static Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.myTimer(123, "127.0.0.1");


    }

    public void myTimer(final long MAC, final String ipAddress) {
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("MAC: " + MAC + "ipAddress:" + ipAddress);
                update();
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000);

    }

    public void update() {
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Updated timer");

            }
        };
        timer.cancel();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 2000);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
 MAC: 123ipAddress:127.0.0.1
 Updated timer
```

Comment: So sorry! it was some kind of mistake, I thought I pasted the mistake!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled
        at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:358)
        at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:170)
        at spb.keepAliveTimer.update(keepAliveTimer.java:37)
        at spb.keepAlive.update(keepAlive.java:58)
        at spb.receptor.keepAlive(receptor.java:475)
        at spb.receptor.run(receptor.java:118)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: You can't cancel and reschedule a TimerTask. You have to create a new instance of the TimerTask each time you schedule it. That is why the code in this answer works, and the code snippet in the question does not.

Comment: I have a requirement inside broadcast receiver with respect to same. Can I perform the below operations inside onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: And also when I try to initialise some thing like this in the class reference ReminderReceiver reminderReceiver = new ReminderReceiver(); it says ava.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at com.nagra.uk.jado.LocalNotifications.ReminderReceiver.<init>(ReminderReceiver.java:20)
        at com.nagra.uk.jado.LocalNotifications.ReminderReceiver.<init>(ReminderReceiver.java:25)

Answer (score 8):

You have to create a new `TimerTask` object every time you restart the `Timer`.
So, create a new one on start. And destroy the Timer with `Timer.cancel()` and `Timer.purge()`.

For eg, I have two Buttons - Start and Stop

```
mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mTimerTask = new TimerTask(); //This creates new TimerTask 
        timer = new Timer(); //Instantiate again, as we Cancel the Timer
        timer.schedule(mTimerTask, 0, 30);
    }
});

mEndButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
    }
});
```