# scheduling runnable tasks in java

Tags: java, timer, scheduling, timer-jobs

I am following up an interesting [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001/resettable-java-timer) on so, on usage of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor for some repeating task.

Scheduling this object returns a ScheduledFuture object which one can use to cancel the next run of the task.

One thing to note here is the task itself is completely decoupled from the schedule--

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
ScheduledFuture nextSchedule = 
    executor.schedule(task, 60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

where-

```
SomeTask task = new SomeTask();
```

So the task itself is not aware of the schedule. Please enlighten if there is a way to get the task to cancel and create a new schedule for itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no reason why the task cannot reference  the `ScheduledExecutorService` and schedule itself to run again if required:

```
// (Need to make variable final *if* it is a local (method) variable.)
final ScheduledExecutorService execService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

// Create re-usable Callable.  In cases where the Callable has state
// we may need to create a new instance each time depending on requirements.
Callable<Void> task = new Callable() {
  public Void call() {
    try {
      doSomeProcessing();
    } finally {
      // Schedule same task to run again (even if processing fails).
      execService.schedule(this, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass the `executor` to the task, so that it can make manipulations with it:

```
SomeTask task = new SomeTask(executor);
```