# Logout when java app is inactive for 30 min problem

Tags: java, authentication, logout

I need to implement logout when  java desktop app is ( when there is no clicking buttons for 30 min ) inactive for 30 min. How to implent this ? Does anybody have any idea ? Is there any observer already for this in Java ?

Comment: A multiuser desktop app?

Comment: Do you want to close the desktop app, end some server connection the app might have or log the user out of the OS?

Answer (score 1):

There's actually two parts to this:

1. detect inactivity
2. log out the user

For the first part, this mostly depends on how you define "inactive". One option: Have some time field for "last acitivy", which gets updated by whatever code implements an acitivy. You could use a [java.util.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) that fires once a minute and checks if "last activity" is more than 30 minutes ago, then logs the user out.

Another option is to use [the approach from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001/resettable-java-timer) to implement a resettable timer, which you could then reset whenever there is activity. Then the logout would be after exactly 30 min, not 30-31 minutes.

As to "logging out the user", this will depend on your OS. Java itself does not have an API for this, but on most platforms you can just invoke an OS binary using `Runtime.exec` or similar. Also note that logging out the user may require elevated privileges on some platforms, so take this into account.

Finally, maybe you could explain what the underlying problem is? Why can't you for example just set the OS screensaver to lock the screen after 30 minutes? Wouldn't that be easier?