# How can I reset a timer in java?

Tags: java, timer, timertask, netbeans-8

```
private void btnGuess1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        private int i = 0;
        public void run(){
            if (i <= 20){
                lblTimer.setText("" + i++);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 1000);
```

This is what I have so far. When I activate this piece of code using a button, the timer never resets. How can I fix this? There are no error message either.

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you expect? when should it be reset?

Comment: When i click a button the timer is suppose to go back to 0 and then start counting to 20 again.

Comment: so you will have to bind and event onclick on the button, and in the code you need to have the reset code

Comment: are you looking at this kind of solution?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001/resettable-java-timer

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Edited code. I looked on line and people said to reset it, you cancel and purge it then create a new timer and use timer.schedule(task, 1000); to restart it but it's not reseting :/

Comment: Yeah I looked at that question but when i tried to use timer.stop(); it gave me a syntax error saying couldn't find symbol.

Comment: declar  Timer timer as GLOBAL, and keep assigning new object in the action performed

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo what do you mean by keep assigning new object in the action performed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `timer` a member of your class and create it in the constructor. You should be cancelling the timer before scheduling your new task. Something like this:

```
 private void btnGuess1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
    timer.cancel();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
       private int i = 0;
       public void run(){
       if (i <= 20){
         lblTimer.setText("" + i++);
      }
    }
};
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: I get an error saying Timer already cancelled when I do this though

Comment: Create a new timer object. See the modified code. and check whether `timer == null` before cancel and remove timer creation from constructor.

Comment: Now the timer is stuck at 0

Comment: You should be using `scheduleAtFixedRate` rather than `schedule`. Look at the java doc.

Comment: Oh okay its working again, just now it seems like the previous timers arn't stopping. So now there are 2 timers going so the label could have 1 timer on and it'd be setting the text and then the second timer is also setting text to it at the same time.

Comment: Ensure you are calling `cancel` on the previous timer object.

Comment: Okay i double checked and now it works :D Thanks so much sir.