# How can I delay a timer task which is generated by ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I use `ScheduledExecutorService` to do a timer task:

```
scheduledExcutorService.schedule(timerTask, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

The TimerTask is a Runnable object:

```
public class TimerTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Usually, I want to do something in 5 minutes, but in some conditions, I need to delay this task.(cancel it and put it to the `ScheduledExecutorService` again with another 5 minutes delay)
But how can I achieve this?

Comment: I am pointing to another thread which has an answer to your query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001/resettable-java-timer

Comment: Actually I know how to do this with Timer and TimerTask, but I prefer doing this by ScheduledExecutorService

Answer (score -1):

Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);//Millisecond

Comment: Add some explanations as well